# jquery say input[name=state] is null but not null

Tags: jquery, input, modal-dialog

i am create modal and incude input modal .

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" id="state" value="123" />
```

but output $('#state').val() is null

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if ( $('#state').val() == '')
    {
    alert('null') // input is full but return null
    }
    else
    {
    alert('not null') // runing else 
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2B3kQ/2/) it works using both the id and name selectors.

Answer (score 1):

[Doesn't behave like that to me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/YLQHG/).

However, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $('#state').val() == '')
    {
        alert('null'); // input is full but return null
    }
    else
    {
        alert('not null'); // runing else 
    }
});
```

Comment: @saeed nassaji: What other scripts do you have on the page? Do you have this online somewhere so we can check it out?

Comment: @saeed nassaji: Dude I can't help you if you don't post the full code. I don't know what is going on. I already showed you that your code is alright the way it is.